How to find the paclet location of a symbol?
Since now most Wolfram functionality is delivered through paclets. How to lookup the location of paclet containing the symbol. For example:
Wolfram has Diff symbol which is coming from a paclet DiffTools. Which is found in the following location in the installation directory:
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram\14.1\SystemFiles\Components\DiffTools

Is there a programmatic way to find the location of paclet which is delivering a specific system function or user added function like FindSymbolPaclet.
FindSymbolPaclet["Diff"] or FindSymbolPaclet["System`Diff"]

Should return:
PacletObject[<|...|>]

Then we can get the path using:
PacletObject[<|...|>]["Location"]


e.g. PacletFind["Channel*"] and #["Location"] & /@ %

@Syed that only finds the Paclet's that match the name but not paclet which contains the specified symbol. For example I want to find the paclet which has the symbol SequenceAlignment.

Information[p] doesn't provide much. It is supposed to have taken over from PacletInformation which is now obsolete.

If the function is already installed, you can write Information[Diff].  The last line of the output: "FullName" gives the paclet name.
